# foreach loop to retrieve list items and create a table

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, foreach, listitem

I am a little confused as to how to display list data in two columns in a webpart.

Here is what i have at the moment (Webpart):

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the code behind for it is the following:

```
foreach (SPListItem oListItem in listItemCollection)
{
    awardYear = oListItem["Year"].ToString();
    awardCategory = oListItem["Category"].ToString();
    awardOrganiser = oListItem["Organiser"].ToString();
    //awardNomWon = oListItem["NominatedWon"].ToString(); //not yet needed
    //need to fingure out how to display images:
    //awardLogo = oListItem["Logo"].ToString();

    //string mydatetime;
    //mydatetime = new DatTime(awardYear).ToString;

    //DateTime convertedaValue = DateTime.Parse(awardYear);
    //string awardYearConverted = convertedaValue.ToString();

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(
        new LiteralControl(awardYear + " " + "|" + "<br/> " + 
                           awardCategory + " " + "|" + "<br/> " + 
                           awardOrganiser + " " + "|" + "<br/><br/>"));

    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(
        new LiteralControl(awardYear + " " + "|" + "<br/> " + 
                           awardCategory + " " + "|" + "<br/> " + 
                           awardOrganiser + " " + "|" + "<br/><br/>"));

    /*
    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(
        new LiteralControl("<table><tr><td>" + awardYear + "</td>" +
                           "<td>&#160;</td>" + "<td>" + 
                           awardCategory + "<br/>" +  
                           awardOrganiser + "</td></tr>" ));
    */

}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to write the details from an "Awards" list and display them in two columns. Currently everything works, but the problem is that data is being repeated in colum1 and column2 of the table. Ideally I was hoping that the "foreach" will create the table and populate it with the details from the list.

There maybe something that I have missed, but I can't really see what that could be. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show some respect and fix the spelling errors in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to describe in the loop which side of the table you want the information in, so I'd suggest this with your loop

```
int modCounter = 0;
foreach (SPListItem oListItem in listItemCollection) 
{ 
    modCounter += 1;
    awardYear = oListItem["Year"].ToString(); 
    awardCategory = oListItem["Category"].ToString(); 
    awardOrganiser = oListItem["Organiser"].ToString(); 

    if(modCounter % 2 == 0) // If modCounter is divisible by 2 (ie even)
    {
         // Add information that goes in first column
    }
    else
    {
         // Add information that goes in second column
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul Leigh, the information for the first and second column is goin to be the same ie they both will display "awardYear, awardCategory, awardOrganiser" only I want it to be displayed in two columns hence why I used a table. In other words item 1 on the list will be displayed in the first column, item 2 on the list will be displayed in the second column, item 3 on the list will be displayed on a new row in the column 1 and so on.....

Comment: Then the code above is exactly what you require. Add your literal controls where I've put the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Building your table using something like the Table control would be much neater and maintainable.

```
<asp:Table ID="MyTable" runat="server" />
```

Then in your code build up the data using TableRow and TableCell objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Rows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rows.aspx)  of [System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx). It means remove your html markup and use Table web control instead.