# I want to display rows in a Document Library in two columns side by side in SharePoint Designer, XSL

Tags: asp.net, xslt, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am working in a rowview template, which basically iterates through all of the row items and displays them according to what i have set them at.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <choose>
    //different images for different when clauses
    </choose>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
    <td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

The above layout is, in general, what I have.

Say you have a document library with documents:
Doc1 
Doc2
Doc3
Doc4

I want these displayed as the following but do now know how to achieve this

```
<tr>
<td>doc1<td><td>doc2<td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>doc3<td><td>doc4<td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Nobody can know unless you provide the source XML document and the wanted output from the transformation. Without an input and output specified, what is it you are asking for??? There is no question here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've added more information & code for you to view. Thank you so much for helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850062/foreach-loop-to-retrieve-list-items-and-create-a-table/8851460#8851460) but for XSL, you need different syntax, though the concept is the same - try the following:

```
<tr>
    <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
        <td>
             <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
        <td>
             <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:if>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link provides the ideal solution for what I was looking for. I just had to alter some of the syntax... Thank you guys for helping me.

http://www.tonymarston.net/xml-xsl/two-column-view.html